# Change detection on injected service's property in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-services, angular2-changedetection

Angular1 veteran here, trying to learn angular2. I have a component with a state service (`MyState` below) that gets injected into itself and its subcomponents. I want to watch for changes on the service's state, then update another member in the top-level component, as follows:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

class Item {
  constructor(public name: string) {}
}

class MyState {
  selectedItems: Item[] = [];
  addItem(item: Item) {
    this.selectedItems.push(item);
  }
}

// subcomponent
@Component({
  selector: '[item]',
  template: `
    <!-- state changed from subcomponent: -->
    <button (click)="state.addItem(model)">
      select item {{model.name}}
    </button>
  `
})
class ItemComponent {
  @Input() model: Item;
  constructor(private state: MyState){}
}

// main component
@Component({
  selector: 'items',
  template: `
    <h1> Available Items: </h1>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of items" item [model]="item"></li>
    </ul>
    <h1> Added Items: </h1>
    <p>{{ addedItemsString }}</p>
  `,
  providers: [MyState],
  directives: [ItemComponent]
})
class ListComponent {
  @Input() items: Item[];
  private addedItemsString: string = '';

  constructor(private state: MyState) {
    // listen for changes to this.state.selectedItems to   
    // call this.updateAddedItemsString
  }

  updateAddedItemsString () {
    this.addItemsString = this.state.selectedItems.map(i => i.name).join(', ');
  }
}
```

My question is: how should I implement the pseudo-code in the ListComponent constructor?

Granted, the `addItemsString` member is contrived and could certainly be done in the template itself, but for the sake of my question assume that `updateAddedItemsString` could do a lot more complicated stuff that updates a separate member of `ListComponent`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use an observable in your service, then you can subscribe to changes. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: Thanks for the lead @GünterZöchbauer! Follow-up question: is it kosher to create an Observable<MyState> as a property of the state itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`BehaviorSubject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject)`<Item[]>` in your service, and have your ListComponent subscribe to changes to that observable array:

```ts
class MyState {
  private _selectedItems: Item[] = [];
  private _selectedItemsSource = new BehaviorSubject<Item[]>(this._selectedItems);
  selectedItems$ = this._selectedItemsSource.asObservable();
  addItem(item: Item) {
    this._selectedItems.push(item);
    this._selectedItemsSource.next(this._selectedItems);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'items',
  template: `<h1> Available Items: </h1>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of items" item [model]="item"></li>
    </ul>
    <h1> Added Items: </h1>
    <div>{{ addedItemsString }}</div>`,
  providers: [MyState],
  directives: [ItemComponent]
})
class ListComponent {
  @Input() items: Item[];
  private addedItemsString: string = '';
  constructor(private state: MyState) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.state.selectedItems$.subscribe(
      items => this.addedItemsString = items.map(i => i.name).join(', '));
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    // prevent memory leak when component is destroyed
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ttvsO6ME3aK9DpaohEHb?p=preview)</kbd>

I emit the entire array each time `next()` is called.  This ensures that any other component that subscribes to the BehaviorSubject later will get the full list. If you don't have that requirement, you could simply emit only new values when `addItem()` is called.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @markrajcok. This seems to work with Subject as well as BehaviorSubject. What's the difference?

Comment: See [the BehaviorSubject link](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject) I provided in the answer.  In summary, BehaviorSubject has the notion of "the current value" so whenever a new Observer subscribes, it will immediately receive the "current value".  A Subject won't do that.  If you use a Subject and emit a value, then later subscribe, the new Observer won't see that previously emitted value -- it will only get future emitted values.  Since you seem to be sharing the current state (rather than just new values), I suggested the BehaviorSubject.

Comment: Thanks for that, and apologies for not following that link first. Helped me out a lot!